# Transferring Google Forms Responses to Google Sheets using Google Apps Script issue

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have some code which adds the responses to a google sheets from Google Forms sheet, the issue I am facing is it adds it to the first column irrelevant of whether it is the correct column. I know this likely caused by the recordarray just assigning it the first free space but I have no idea how to specify the column based on the title? Thanks for any help

```
function onFormSubmit(event) {

record_array = []

var form = FormApp.openById('12sDsbDUiYvq5Ba2XurnXKh7S5gfM-VDaxzqLG_5n3ao'); // Form ID
var formResponses = form.getResponses();
var formCount = formResponses.length;

var formResponse = formResponses[formCount - 1];
var itemResponses = formResponse.getItemResponses();

for (var j = 0; j < itemResponses.length; j++) {
var itemResponse = itemResponses[j];
var title = itemResponse.getItem().getTitle();
var answer = itemResponse.getResponse();

Logger.log(title);
Logger.log(answer);

record_array.push(answer);
}

AddRecord(record_array[0], record_array[1], record_array[2], record_array[3], record_array[4], 
record_array[5], record_array[6], record_array[7], record_array[8]);

}

function AddRecord(q1, q2, q3, q4, q5, q6, q7, q8) {
var url = 
 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZHlvt_Blqe7rDheIxVjvYhneoZfZPGiGbXFSIri6u1c/edit#gid=0';   
//URL OF GOOGLE SHEET;
var ss= SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
var dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet7");
dataSheet.appendRow([q1, q2, q3, q4, q5, q6, q7, q8, new Date()]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It won't let me post a screenshot in the comments, so for now this is just a comment but I will come back and try and answer based on response. Just wondering, is there a reason that the default behavior of Google Forms saving to a Google Sheet won't work for you? Or rather, what is the problem you are trying to solve by scripting to move the answers from the form to a sheet? Below is an image of a form, you can click the green Sheets logo pictured and it will automatically set up a Sheet to collect form responses. This sheet will also auto-update with any new responses. I've found that it's much easier to manipulate the data once it is already in a Sheet.

[image: Google Forms]

Comment: Thank you for coming back to me, yes I have used the in built feature the one issue is that ultimately I wouldn't use sheet but for now I am happy to use a sheet. The point of the system is that they answer a few questions and dependent on the answers it will generate a code this code is a product code with version as the last digit and so after product code 01 it will increment to PP02, PP03, I thought using Apps script would be better for future proofing.

Comment: I would recommend using the default while you are using a sheet. It seems like your issues are caused mostly by copying over from the form to the sheet, so avoiding that would solve the problem. Plus it will allow you to keep the sheet version running for the users while you work on developing the version without a sheet attached.